# Using Browserify with Reactjs

Tags: parsing, bundle, require, reactjs, browserify

I am just getting started on a new project which I would like to write in ReactJS. I am trying to use Broserify to bundle everything so that I can have it in multiple js files.

However, when I try to bundle my react file (`browserify main.js > bundle.js`), I get this error:
"Error: Parsing file /Users/Kathleen/Documents/Referral_Site/main.js: Unexpected token (3:4)"

main.js looks like this:

```
var Lander = require('./lander');
React.render(
    <Lander />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

What's breaking the parser? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: also, I included react in the surrounding html like this:

```
<script src="http://fb.me/react-0.12.2.js"></script>
```

is there some way that I need to include it in main.js as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must compile JSX to plain JS first, there is plugin for browserify.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactify